# return class from function in c#

Tags: c#, class

Can I return class object from function in c# as a return value instead return string or int or ..etc

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want a function that returns a class (i.e., a type, not an instance), or do you want a function that returns type `object` (System.Object)?

Answer (score 13):

A class object in C# is a Type. So you can definitely return it from a function:

```
public Type Foo() {
    return typeof(string);
}

public Type Bar() {
    return someNonNullVariable.GetType();
}
```

Comment: ok what is the wrong in this function  
public Bill_spec Get_Bill_Items(string getbillnum, Bill_spec current_bill)
{ return current_bill;}

Comment: You're returning an instance of Bill_spec, not a class object. (I'm ignoring the fact that you're simply returning one of the parameters, which makes for an odd function.)

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming that you want to return a instance of a class from the function, then the answer is yes.  An instance of a class is nothing more than an object like basically everything else in .NET.

Example:

```
public class MeaningfulClassName
{  
    public int Val1;
    public string Val2;
    ....
}

public class Processor
{
    public MeaningfulClassName MyFunction(int something, string somethingelse)
    {
        var ret = new MeaningfulClassName();

        ....

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to return a class based on a string variable. All the examples I found used Type and typeof which have slightly different things accessible to the object. This is the first and only solution I found that brings back the class that I can use, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I read your question as if a method can return a class. I would, presently, dare say No.  Presently is 2018-04-05

Below I am using `System.Class`, a class most famous for `System.Class.WriteLine`.

One *can not* declare

```
Func<System.Class> C => System.Class;
```

to be able to

```
C.WriteLine("Hello world!");
```

---

Someone Please prove me Wrong!
I would really love the functionality as it would help med mock a static.