# How to Specify a Class as a Method Return Type

Tags: c#, class, syntax, properties

I am viewing a method that begins with the syntax:

```
private myClass MyMethod(myArgs)
```

What is the unattached **myClass** after the access modifier? I was under the impression a return type was limited to bool, int, or other simple types, not an entire class.

Comment: That is type of the property, or [the return type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) of the method, respectively. If you call `MyMethod()`, it will return an instance of a class named `myClass`, or it might return `null`. If you try to assign anything to `MyProp` but a `myClass` or `null`, the compiler will not allow you to do that. That means that when you *use* the value of `MyProp`, you can be assured that the thing it holds will be either `null`, or `myClass`.

Comment: There are some further caveats, but that's the essence of it.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now and is very helpful! I can find the examples on this post now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191047/return-class-from-function-in-c-sharp.

Comment: I've tried to revise and make the question as simple as possible. Ed Plunkett answered the original question in a very quick, useful, and succinct manner, so I don't understand why the question is on hold for being too broad. I've done a lot of reading and there are not a lot of simple examples of this particular aspect of C#. On this site, there is only one other relevant question which is vague and weakly worded without a marked answer. I understand it is not a complex concept, but it is important nonetheless, as this is a site for developers of all levels.

Comment: Questions like this are generally closed. IMO there's a legitimate debate whether they should be: At a very early stage in learning programming, you *can't* be expected to know what to google to find the answers. At any rate, you did get your question answered.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was kindly answered above by [Ed Plunkett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424129/ed-plunkett).

> That is type of the property, or [the return type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) of the method,
>   respectively. If you call MyMethod(), it will return an instance of a
>   class named myClass, or it might return null. If you try to assign
>   anything to MyProp but a myClass or null, the compiler will not allow
>   you to do that. That means that when you *use* the value of MyProp, you
>   can be assured that the thing it holds will be either null, or
>   myClass.

There is further information here:
[return class from function in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191047/return-class-from-function-in-c-sharp).